# Nhibernate database connection in MySql using Asp& C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, nhibernate

I'm trying to save the values in database. But here I can able to save only once after executing. During second time it shows inner exception as "{"Duplicate entry '' for key 1"}"

Comment: You'll need to give us a little more information than that! posting the nhibernate mappings and the code where you save the "values" would be a start

Comment: Mapping File:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="WebApplication1.Employee,WebApplication1 " table="emp">
    <id name="Emp_Id" column="Emp_Id" type="string">
      <generator class="native"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="Hr_type" column="Hr_type" type="String"></property>
    <property name="Prefix" column="Prefix" type="String"></property></class>
</hibernate-mapping>

Comment: Mapping File:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
Its cleared. Here I used generator class type as "native". And I changed into assigned. Nw it works... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're assigning the same key to a new object. I mean maybe you're trying to Save a new object in the database with the same key/Id. If you're updating the object with Id/Key = 1 you should use an update command instead.

As Jonny Cundall said we need more information about your NHibernate mapping to see what you're doing...

Do this for you identity:

```
<!-- Identity mapping -->
<id name="Emp_Id">
<column name="Emp_Id" />
<generator class="native" />
</id>
```

Advice: do not use string as your data type for an identity column.

Comment: Here I'm using Id as string. Becoz the id doesn't have only integer values. It contains year of joining, Dept name and Number. So here I used as string. And thanks a lot... Like Genius u guys help us to get more from u.